# Determine the cases, $L^0\left(\lambda\right)$ and $L^\infty\left(\lambda\right)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Consider the following function:
$$g\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}, & \text{if} \ x\in\left(1,\infty\right)\\
0, & \text{if} \ x \in \left(-\infty, 1\right]
\end{cases}$$
Determine the set $\{p\in\left[0, \infty\right] : g\in\mathcal L^p\left(\lambda\right)\}$.
I know that the set is equal to $\left(1, \infty\right]$. But I am not sure how to calculate the cases $p=0$ and $p=\infty$.
In my textbook we have the following definitions for $p=0$ and $p=\infty$:
$$\mathcal L^\infty\left(\mu\right)=\{f\in\mathcal M\left(\mathcal E\right) : \exists R>0 : |f| \leq R \ \ \mu\text{-almost everywhere}\}$$
and
$$\mathcal L^0\left(\mu\right)=\{f\in\mathcal M\left(\mathcal E\right) : \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mu\left(\{|f|\geq t\}\right)=0\}$$
where $\mathcal M\left(\mathcal E\right)=\{f : X \rightarrow\mathbb R : f \ \ \text{is} \ \mathcal E \text{-}\mathcal B\left(\mathbb R\right)\text{- measurable}\}$.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: This is just application of the definitions. What is causing trouble? Determine the measure of the sets $\{ |g|\le t\}$ and $\{ |g|>R\}$

Comment: So for $p=0$, we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mu\left(\{|\frac{1}{x}| \geq t\}\right)$?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $|g(x)|≤ 1$
- $|1/x| ≥ t \iff |x| < 1/t$ ... what is the size of the set $\{x\in(1,\infty) : |x|<1/t\}$ ?

Comment: I guess that we have to take the measure of the set then, so $\lambda\left(\{x\in\left(1, \infty\right) : |x| < 1/t\}\right)$. Since we know that $\lambda\left(\left(a, \infty\right)\right)=\infty$, then $\lambda\left(\{x\in\left(1, \infty\right) : |x| < 1/t\}\right)=\infty$? Or is that wrong?

Comment: For the case where $p=\infty$, we have that, for any $n\in\mathbb N$, for $x\in\left(1, n^2\right)$, $g\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{n^2}$ for $x\in\left(1, n^2\right)$, since $\left(1, n^2\right)$ has a positive measure for $n>1$. Then $||g||_\infty<\frac{1}{n^2}$ which is true for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and will have that $||g||_\infty<\infty$. Can you verify this.